# Proving reasoning by cases. $P(X \mid Y) = \sum_{z} P(X,z \mid Y)$

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $X, Y , Z$ be random variables, then $P(X \mid Y) = \sum_{z} P(X,z \mid Y)$.

I have a sketch of the proof but I do not know if it is correct: 
$$\sum_{z} P(X,z \mid Y) = \sum_{z} \frac{P(X,Y,z)}{P(Y)} =$$
$$\frac{\sum_{z}P(X,Y,z)}{P(Y)}$$
Then by the fact that the joint probability distribution must be consistent with the marginal probability: 
$$\sum_{z}P(X,Y,z) = P(X,Y) $$
Completing the proof.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the Z's.

Comment: really? that is all the book I'm using says... You mean in the proof statement or my proof?

Comment: The proof seems ok if you are summing $z$ over all the support points of $Z$ (I assume you mean there is a random variable $Z$ in the context). It essentially says that the law of total probability also applicable on conditional probability (in fact a conditional probability share all the properties from the "unconditional" probability we learn)

Comment: When you say _support points_, do you mean all the possible values that the random variable $Z$ can take? And yeah it might be a good idea to specify that there is a random variable $Z$ in the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is essentially correct except $X,Y,z$ are not events; they are two random variables and a value. $X=x, Y=y, Z=z$ are events.

> For *discrete* random variables $X,Y,Z$, we use the Law of Total Probability to state:
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \mathsf P(X {=} x \mid Y{=}y) \; & =\; \mathsf P(X{=}x,Y{=}y)\,/\,\mathsf P(Y{=}y)
> & \textsf{iff } \mathsf P(Y{=}y)\neq 0
> \\[1ex] & = \; \sum\limits_{z\in \mathcal Z}\mathsf P(X {=} x, Z{=}z, Y{=}y)\,/\,\mathsf P(Y{=}y) &\textrm{where }\mathcal Z\textrm{ is the support of }Z
> \\[2ex]\therefore \mathsf P(X {=} x \mid Y{=}y)  & =\; \sum\limits_{z\in \mathcal Z}\mathsf P(X {=} x, Z{=}z\mid Y{=}y)
> & \Box
> \end{align}$$